# Does this group theory question require an additional hypothesis?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

The problem is to

> Show that if $G$ is a finite group and for all nontrivial elements $a, b$ there exists an automorphism taking $a$ to $b$, then $G$ is a $C_p$ vector space, where $C_p$ is the group of prime order $p$.

---

> My question is if an additional hypothesis that $G$ is abelian is needed.

I cannot seem to prove that $G$ is abelian from the hypotheses.

Of course, the point is that all the elements of $G$ have the same prime order $p$.

But I cannot seem to get the result without showing $G$ is abelian, in which case the normality of all subgroups gives what I want.

Comment: If the additional hypothesis is not necessary, then please don't answer the question, by the way.

Comment: Are you sure you can't show that the group is already abelian by your hypothesis?

Comment: Can you?  I gave it a try but not too hard of a try.

Comment: I just saw this result online in the case of abelian groups.  But my professor phrased it this way, and I thought he was just trying to be sneaky about saying every element has the same order.  But now I'm not so sure.

Comment: These hypotheses can show that $G$ is abelian, so this solves the problem.

Comment: Nice, can you share your proof?

Answer (score 1):

We may assume $G$ is not trivial.  As mentioned in the statement of the problem, it is quick to go from the hypotheses to the fact that $G$ is a $p$-group.  Now, every nontrivial $p$-group has a nontrivial center.  Let $z$ be some nonzero element of the center.  Given $g ,h \in G$, by hypothesis we may choose an automorphism $\phi$ carrying $g$ to $z$.  Then, $\phi(gh) = \phi(g)\phi(h) = \phi(h)\phi(g) = \phi(hg)$.  Since $\phi$ is injective, we see that $gh = hg$.  So, $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Note that for a group automorphism $\phi$, the order of $g$ = order of $\phi(g)$. So what can be said about the order of G?